# asp.net cookie not saved

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong here.
Why the Cookie data is not stored when I reload the page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      // it is always null !!!!               
      if (Response.Cookies["user_id"].Value != null) 
      {
          //code never gets here
      }
   }
}
```

and this is the code for storing the cookie (after clicking a checkbox):

```
protected void CheckBoxRememberMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cookies["user_id"].Value = tbUserID.Text;
    Response.Cookies["user_id"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);
}
```

So: I click on the checkbox, the value of tbUserID textbox is stored in the HttpCookie, then I reload the page (refresh) and the value is null.

Any idea ?

Comment: Check the server date/time. Also, `Page_Load` will always execute before `CheckBoxRememberMe_Click`, so I would only expect a cookie after the second loading of the page (following the checkbox being clicked).

Comment: As I've mentioned, I'm checking Page_Load on refreshing the page. So I'm sure the setting of the value is called before reading the value (on the second load of the page).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When checking for the cookie you want to be making a request rather than adding the cookie to the response.

```
   if (Request.Cookies["user_id"].Value != null) 
   {
       //code should get here
   }
```

Comment: That's it ! I should have used Request.Cookies